# Single Nginx Docker vs Multiple Nginx Docker for websites

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Forgive me if I am asking a stupid question, but I am building a server where I will host multiple Flask websites Docker Container using Nginx Docker. My question now is: is it better to have one main nginx docker container and then host all my Websites Docker containers on it or have an Nginx docker container for each application with docker compose?

I want to know in terms of resource handling and efficiency which one is better to go for ?

Comment: What approach did you eventually choose?

Comment: I am now using a docker container for each websites that i host. I find this a better approach for my case. I can separately maintain each one and there is also no single point of failure :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes I came to the same conclusion. Do you also use another nginx container as a "router", which passes requests to each of the other nginx containers? I see some people do that too, but I'm not sure if it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many roads lead to Rome. If you follow the "microservice approach", i.e. you are closer to the backend with the Nginx paths etc., you have the advantage that you can change or break one service without having a big impact on the others.

We have DNS -> F5 -> Nginx -> Nginx -> backend at work for example. No problems.

An Nginx (container) does not consume many resources, partly because it is programmed in C.

Comment: So basically it is better to have a Nginx container for each website docker container ?

Comment: Yes. But everything has advantages and disadvantages. Besides redundancy and divide-and-conquer, for example, I would also look at the time spent, KISS and security. Of course, it is easier to do everything in one, but then all services go down when you have to restart or have a problem with this one Nginx.

Comment: This was very instructive. I was afraid having many nginx docker containers would take a lot of resources. Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: No problem. How many instances of Flask do you want to run?

Comment: I currently have 2 APIs and 2 websites. This might increase in the future ...

Comment: A Nginx can handle as many requests as you can't follow quickly while looking at the log file with `tail -f` and spend maybe 300 MB of RAM.

Comment: @qräbnö You have one nginx container for each app's stack - if n app containers then n nginx containers. Do you also use another nginx container, at the front, as a "router", which passes requests to the other nginx containers? Is it even necessary?